# What's the name of the shoe covers one must use when walking into some parts of a hospital?

Tags: choix-de-mot, noms

Some time ago, when my third kid was about to be born, I noticed that in Spanish the shoe covers you must use when walking into the zone where babies are born for hygiene purposes are called "papis" in Spanish (although not generally). [I asked](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28592/12637) why is that so (question in Spanish), but the [only answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28627/12637) I could get was that it probably comes from French *papillote*, as the covers are quite like the piece of paper that covers the food in the technique of the same name.

It seems that in French you can use *[papillote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/papillote)* as:

1. A wrapper or packet for food during cooking.
2. A small piece of paper on which women roll up their hair to make it curl.
3. A vividly coloured paper wrap for crackers and other sweets.

But can it also be used for these covers?

[image: Papis]
<sub>Yes, I took that picture of my own shoes just a couple of hours before the birth.</sub>

Or is there another word for this? I'm just trying to prove that the theory I got as an answer in my question is plausible.

Comment: Papillote also means a chocolate wrapped in a fancy piece of paper that we use to give at christmas time (I'd even say that's the main usage of this word)

Comment: @stbr you're right, I missed that meaning from the Wiktionary. I added it to the list, thank you.

Comment: @stbr > I would say the main usage is the first one mentionned in the question, the cooking one. The one you descibe is, I think, limited to (some regions of) France, while the "cooking" one is at least used in Belgium too.

Answer (score 3):

They seem to be called "couvre chaussures" ou "sur chaussures":

https://www.girodmedical.com/hygiene/protection-a-usage-unique/couvre-chaussures.html

https://www.az-fournitures.com/2850-mensch-sur-chaussure-jetable-hygiene-bleu.html

Comment: Note that "couvre chaussure" is quite generic, so the exact item it describes depends on the context. For example you can use a couvre chaussure [when cycling](https://www.ekoi.fr/fr/36-couvre-chaussure-velo-hiver), [walking in the rain](https://www.cdiscount.com/auto/bottes-moto-chaussures/couvre-chaussure-pluie-housse-de-chaussures-etanch/f-13324-mp09738738.html) or simply [at home](https://www.amazon.fr/FOCCTS-Surchaussures-R%C3%A9utilisables-Antid%C3%A9rapant-informatique/dp/B07BLK7HJ9/ref=lp_1764991031_1_1_sspa?s=shoes&ie=UTF8&qid=1560957303&sr=1-1-spons&psc=1)

Comment: @LaurentS. You're right. I found that often the adjective "jetable" is added to specify it is a disposable item, as in "couvre chaussures jetable".

Comment: _Chausson de protection jetable_ est un autre terme utilisé